# How can I fix, Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page. I have tried the usual

Tags: wp-admin

I have just migrated a site to a new server.

All seemed to go well but now I am getting an error "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.".

I have access to FTP and to PHP MyAdmin.

I can login, and see myself logged in on the front end, but I do not have a dropdown to see the "dashboard".  As you can see from this screenshot, I can visit `/wp-admin` and I can login.  To me this stinks of a permissions issue.  As soon as I am logged in I am no longer able to visit `/wp-admin` and get the error.

[image: Logged In]

I used PHP MyAdmin to create a new user via SQL.
I changed the `qt_usermeta` > `wp_capabilities` to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}`

I ensured `wp_user_level` has a `meta_value` of `10`

I renamed the **plugins folder** to **plugins-disabled**.

I renamed **wordfence-waf.php** to **--wordpress-waf.php**

I renamed **.htaccess** to **htaccess.txt**

I changed the PHP version from 7.2 down to 5.6 in case the theme did not support it.

I ensured all folders were 755 and files were 655.

I turned on WP_DEBUG but received no errors.

Can anyone think of anything I may have missed?  This stinks of a permissions issue to me.

Comment: `"Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."` not only mean you don't have access level, if that admin page does not exist, it also say so. Would you mind telling more, is all admin page display the same message and so on?

Comment: I see the /wp-admin login page.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: You may try to turn on debug log with output file according to [WP Debug](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) see if there is any error output to the error log when you login. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that didn't work either

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a WordPress problem, somehow something else is causing this to happen.  The last host mentioned having installed some extra security stuff but I don't know what that could be.

Comment: Maybe you could ask the host then to see what is changed.

Comment: We left the host, that's what changed.  Never mind I'll speed up with the new site release instead.